# How to get Mathematica to make further simplifications to conditional expressions than it has already made?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, logic

I have the following Mathematica result under the assumption that `{ax, bx, px, ay, by, py} \[Element] Reals`, and after refinement by `Simplify`:

```
ConditionalExpression[-((
  ay/Sqrt[(ax - px)^2 + (ay - py)^2] - by/
   Sqrt[(bx - px)^2 + (by - 
      py)^2] + (-(1/Sqrt[(ax - px)^2 + (ay - py)^2]) + 1/
      Sqrt[(bx - px)^2 + (by - py)^2]) py)/(
  ay (bx - px) + by px - bx py + ax (-by + py))), 
 Im[((ax - bx) (ax - px) + (ay - by) (ay - py) - 
     I Abs[ay bx - ax by - ay px + by px + ax py - bx py])/((ax - 
       bx)^2 + (ay - by)^2)] < 0 || 
  Re[((ax - bx) (ax - px) + (ay - by) (ay - py) - 
     I Abs[ay bx - ax by - ay px + by px + ax py - bx py])/((ax - 
       bx)^2 + (ay - by)^2)] < 0 || 
  Im[((ax - bx) (ax - px) + (ay - by) (ay - py) - 
     I Abs[ay bx - ax by - ay px + by px + ax py - bx py])/((ax - 
       bx)^2 + (ay - by)^2)] > 0 || 
  Re[((ax - bx) (ax - px) + (ay - by) (ay - py) - 
     I Abs[ay bx - ax by - ay px + by px + ax py - bx py])/((ax - 
       bx)^2 + (ay - by)^2)] > 1]
```

Pictorially, it's this:

[image]

If you consider the first part of the OR, can you confirm that the `Im[...] < 0` is nothing more than the stuff in the absolute value brackets (`Abs[ay bx - ax by - ay px + by px + ax py - bx py]`) being greater than zero?

Similar simplifications can be made for the rest of the conditions. How do I get Mathematica to execute these simplifications on its own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the expression in the question designated `z`, the conditions in the `ConditionalExpression` are given by `z[[2]]`, which can be simplified by

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[z[[2]]], {ax, bx, px, ay, by, py} ∈ Reals]
(* ((ax - bx)^2 + (ay - by)^2) Abs[ay (bx - px) + by px - bx py + ax (-by + py)] > 0
|| ((ax - bx)^2 + (ay - by)^2) (ax^2 + ay^2 + bx px - ax (bx + px) + by py - ay (by + py)) < 0
|| ((ax - bx)^2 + (ay - by)^2) ((ax - bx) (bx - px) + (ay - by) (by - py)) > 0 *)
```

Is this the sort of thing you had in mind?

Comment: Yes! I don't understand. How did this end up working when you put it this way?

Comment: My theory on why this works, having read up on `ComplexExpand`: while I used `Assumptions` to specify that all variables are real in an Integrate command which created `z`, I did not use it when applying `FullSimplify`.

Comment: Also, consider the result we get now: the first and third disjunct(`((ax - bx)^2 + (ay - by)^2) Sqrt[(ay bx - ax by - ay px + by px + ax py - bx py)^2] > 0 || ((ax - bx)^2 + (ay - by)^2) Sqrt[(ay bx - ax by - ay px + by px + ax py - bx py)^2] < 0`) is always true! This is because squaring a number always return a positive result, adding two positive numbers results in a positive number, and taking the square root returns a positive and negative root.So, the conditional is not even necessary because these two branches will always be true?

Comment: @user89  Actually, squaring a real number does not always return a positive result.  It could return zero.  However, Mathematica  could have dropped the second condition in your last comment, because that quantity is never negative.  I have modified my answer to make this happen.

Comment: You're right, and thank you very much for showing me this!